# IIS6 WCF service seems to still point to an older build despite showing the correct latest build virtual directory

Tags: wcf, iis-6, virtual-directory

I just deployed a new version of a WCF service to IIS6 via a powershell script which keeps previous versions (builds) of the service in the file system but points the application to the newest build virtual directory.

But upon testing the service I noticed that the behavior of the service was consistent with the previous version of the service not the latest (as latest build has a fix for an issue in the previous build, which I was testing).

So I checked the application's virtual directory path in IIS and it shows the correct (latest) build virtual directory. So I decompile the DLLs in the bin and indeed they are the latest.

I even attempted to remote debug the service and no break point was being hit despite the PIDs of the service and the attached process matching.

I then tried to switch the virtual directory back to the old one in order to switch it back to the new one (in the case of some glitch or bug in IIS or something) but when I set it to the old virtual directory the change would not persist, even after an iisreset.

At this point I am not sure what is causing this issue, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you reset IIS or restart app pool post deployment?

Comment: Try deleting temporaty files from location C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files OR C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files. Use appropriate path as per your framework.

Comment: Tried this and still the old behavior is happening. I even deleted the old virtual directories and iisreset and bounced the server, still with the same result. The DLLs are the same on my dev machine and on the server and the DB they point to are the same but still I am getting different results.